# retrieve values and export to workspace from a radiobutton in a buttongroup

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm trying to modify this gui http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20604-3d-slice-viewer because I'd like to add a feature. This new feature is to assess diseases, I mean if the slice that is currently on the viewer has disease the user click yes, otherwise click no. And this should be done several time per patient. For this learning purposes I'm using mri data from matlab.

The issue is that I added a new box (buttongroup) with two radiobutton by using guide. But I can't get any value out of the gui. When I only use get(eventdata.NewValue, 'Tag'), everytime that I click in the buttons I can see in the command window the value of the button, but I don't know how to save these clicks. I have tried without success the follow:

```
% --- Executes when selected object is changed in Assess.
function Assess_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to the selected object in EmphyAssess 
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UIBUTTONGROUP)
%   EventName: string 'SelectionChanged' (read only)
%   OldValue: handle of the previously selected object or empty if none was selected
%   NewValue: handle of the currently selected object
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')   % Get Tag of selected object
    case '1'
        value = 1; 
        Setappdata(hObject,'result', value); 

      case '2'
          value= 0; 
          Setappdata(hObject,'result', value); 

end

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = SliceBrowserIsa_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure

   varargout{1} = getappdata(hObject,'result');
```

Comment: To store values in the figure object use guidata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the handles object using `guidata(hObject,handles)` - [look here for more info](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html). After that you should be able to access the value.

Your question also mentions exporting to workspace - you could use `assignin('base', 'variable', value)` - [see here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

Comment: Hi @cwissy,

I have modified my code as you suggested in the first example by using guidata(hObject, handles) but still I can't get the values outside the GUI. I tried the assigning but nothing happens.

Any other ideas? maybe the problem is that I'm not using it well, could you maybe set an example for me?

Thanks

Comment: if you put `assignin('base','result',value)` you should have a `result` variable in the workspace. Have you tried debugging?